# A form creates twice on application's FormCreate event

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to load a form when my main form starts. And I do it using `ShowModal`. Also that form is not an auto create form so I have to create it first with `application.CreateForm`.

My problem is when I try to load the form in `FormCreate` event, it load the form twice and when I close the form my whole app closes.

Here is my code:

```
procedure Tfrm_main.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  username, password : string;
begin
  username := ini.ReadString('user','username','');
  if username = '' then
  begin
    application.CreateForm(Tfrm_user,frm_user);
    frm_user.ShowModal;
  end;
end;
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: *" I have to create it first with application.CreateForm"* - You don't have to. Use `frm_user := Tfrm_user.Create(Application)` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in your question is called from the call to `Application.CreateForm` that creates the main form. Then you call `Application.CreateForm` again, recursively, and that results in the `Tfrm_user` instance becoming the main form.

It's well known that the first form created by `Application.CreateForm` becomes the main form. Here, you call `Application.CreateForm` to create the main form. But before the code of `Application.CreateForm` gets to determine what the VCL considers to be the main form, the recursive call to `Application.CreateForm` executes. All the way to the end, and in doing so determines the main form to be the secondary form made with the recursive call.

You then show the secondary form modally. Later you call `Application.Run` which shows the VCL main form, your secondary form. Again. And then you close it. Which closes the program, because that's what happen when you close the VCL main form.

My advice is to call `Application.CreateForm` exactly once in the life of your program. So, in the `OnCreate` handler create the other form like this:

```
frm_user := Tfrm_user.Create(Application);
```

Or perhaps let the main form be the owner. And certainly consider not using the global variable `frm_user`. I'd remove that.

Or another option would be to show the secondary form modally before you make the call to `Application.CreateForm`.

Comment: IOW, `Application.CreateForm` has recursed, with the inner (2nd) call returning first and hence setting the main form. Trying to elaborate the 1st paragraph... Still not an exact description though..

Answer (score 5):

You're getting bitten by an order-of-operations issue.

If you look at the code to `TApplication.CreateForm`, you'll see that things happen in this order:

- Create a new form of the appropriate type.
- If FMainForm = nil, assign this new form to it.
- Later, TApplication.Run calls `FMainForm.Show;`

But when the program is setting up your principal form:

- It first creates it, which calls the `OnFormCreate` event handler.  Then the event handler calls `TApplication.CreateForm`, (before the first one has returned) which creates the new form, sees that `FMainForm` is not assigned and assigns this form to it, then returns.
- Your `FormCreate` then shows this form as a modal, then returns.
- Things unwind a little, and we're back to the original `TApplication.CreateForm`, which goes on to the next part, sees FMainForm already assigned, and does not assign it.
- Then it returns, and `TApplication.Run` gets called, which shows the main form... the wrong one.

IF you want to create the new form, call the constructor instead: `frm_user := Tfrm_user.Create(Application);`  Really, `TApplication.CreateForm` should *only* be used the one time, to set up the main form.  It's kind of a hack that can make trouble for you if you don't know exactly how it works.